# How to catch a rejected promise in a new expression node v14.4.0 "for await ... of"

Tags: node.js, promise, for-await

I emulated 3 promises - two resolved, one rejected, wrapped a try-catch function, but I still get warnings in the console: (node: 4159) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

```
    const emulate = (id, ms) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (ms > 1500) reject(id);
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve(id);
        }, ms);
      });

    const promises = [
      emulate(1, 500),
      emulate(2, 1000),
      emulate(3, 2000)
    ];

    async function stepByStepResolve() {
      try {
        for await (const promise of promises)
          console.log(promise);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('Err:', e);
      }
    }

    stepByStepResolve();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `emulate(3, 2000)` in the `promises` array, a promise is created, and will get rejected on the next phase of the event loop, except if you are listening to it and handling it, before that. Now, in the `for loop`, you are listening to all 3 promises in order, and since `emulate(3, 2000)` is being listened to last, it would have already been rejected by the time you iterate to it.

I can suggest two solutions to this:

**Solution 1**: Simply place `emulate(3, 2000)` as the first element in the array

```
let promises = [
  emulate(3, 2000),
  emulate(1, 500),
  emulate(2, 1000),
];
```

This will allow it to be listened to, and caught before it gets rejected.

**Solution 2** (this is more of a suggestion): use a generator instead of an array, like this:

```
function* promisesGenerator() {
  yield emulate(3, 2000);
  yield emulate(1, 500);
  yield emulate(2, 1000);
}

async function stepByStepResolve() {
  try {
    for await (const promise of promisesGenerator())
      console.log(promise);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Err:', e);
  }
}

stepByStepResolve();
```

This will keep the promises from being created before the `for loop`, and will the be created one by one as you iterate through the generator.